How to center Word Document output text in RMarkdown
I'm currently working on a script in RMarkdown and I'm having a problem centering my text. I don't have a problem with the YAML except for the date since I can't modify the style format of the date in the Word template. As a workaround, I tried to put the date at the section after the YAML but then I'm still having a problem centering the date in the Word template. I tried using html tags but it did not help.
---
title: "Situation Report"
subtitle: "Ebola outbreak in Sierra Leone"
author: "Michael John P. Sabido"
output:
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: "template.docx"

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
(insert 3 backticks here to close the r chuck)

<center> Date of report: `r format(Sys.Date(), "%d %b %Y")` </center>

Can you help me with this? Thank you!

A centering can be created using the two packages officedown and officer:
install.packages(c("officedown","officer"))

Using officedown, the output is now an officedown docx document:
---
title: "Situation Report"
author: "The Author" 
subtitle: Ebola outbreak in Sierra Leone
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(officer)
```

some text

```{r Centering1}

ft_text<-fp_text(color="black", bold=F, font.size=15, font.family="Calibri (Body)")
fp_center<-fp_par(line_spacing = 1.5, text.align="center")
fpar(ftext(paste("Date of report:", format(Sys.Date(), "%d %b %Y"), sep=" "), ft_text), fp_p=fp_center)
```

more text

Paste is used here to combine the generated (current) date with the rest of the title. The centering is specified in fp_center and the rest of the text font options are in ft_text.
Compile in RStudio with Knit --> Knit to officedown.
More information in this link
